Taking CC Payments over RTP instead of SRTP and PCI Compliance?
I couldn't find any information on this with a straight forward answer. I may have been googling the wrong thing.
We have several IVRs and 2 of them accept credit card payments over the phone. Both of those IVRs use RTP instead of SRTP or some secure/encrypt layer. How concerning is this from a security perspective? What are the minimum PCI compliance requirements for those accepting CC payments over VOIP?

Logging is a clear cut concern and a few other things. I am just unaware of security concerns and srtp vs rtp.
